# FFMPEG tee muxer giving "Output file #0 does not contain any stream"

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to create two streams: one is mpegts UDP stream another - rtmp to Twitch servers.

This command works:

```
  ffmpeg -threads:v 2 -threads:a 16 -filter_threads 2 -thread_queue_size 16 -y \
 -f dshow -video_size 1920x1080 -pixel_format uyvy422 -framerate 25 -rtbufsize 500M -i video="Decklink Video Capture" \
 -f dshow -rtbufsize 100M -i audio="Decklink Audio Capture" \
 -preset ultrafast -c:v libx264 -tune zerolatency -b:v 900k -map 0:v:0 -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:5555 \ 
 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -tune zerolatency -f flv rtmp://live-fra05.twitch.tv/app/stream_key
```

But it requires double the encoding CPU power.

So, following [this](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Creating%20multiple%20outputs#Teepseudo-muxer), I rewrote the command like this:

```
ffmpeg -threads:v 2 -threads:a 16 -filter_threads 2 -thread_queue_size 16 -y \
 -f dshow -video_size 1920x1080 -pixel_format uyvy422 -framerate 25 -rtbufsize 500M -i video="Decklink Video Capture" \
 -f dshow -rtbufsize 100M -i audio="Decklink Audio Capture" \
 -preset ultrafast -c:v libx264 -tune zerolatency -b:v 900k \
 -f tee "[select=\'0:v:0\':f=mpegts]udp://127.0.0.1:5555|[select=\'0:v:0,1:a:0\':f=flv]rtmp://live-fra05.twitch.tv/app/stream_key"
```

By writing `-f tee "[select=\'0:v:0\':f=mpegts]udp://127.0.0.1:5555|[select=\'0:v:0,1:a:0\':f=flv]rtmp://live-fra05.twitch.tv/app/stream_key"`, I mean:

- create UDP stream at udp://127.0.0.1:5555 and only include video stream from **"Decklink Video Capture"**
- create RTMP stream where we include the same video stream as above and also the audio stream from **"Decklink Audio Capture"**

I get the error message:

```
Output file #0 does not contain any stream
```

How do I fix this? I assume I made a mistake in the command.

Answer (score 0):

As the link shows, streams have to be mapped.

```
ffmpeg -thread_queue_size 16 -y \
 -f dshow -video_size 1920x1080 -pixel_format uyvy422 -framerate 25 -rtbufsize 500M -i video="Decklink Video Capture" \
 -f dshow -rtbufsize 100M -i audio="Decklink Audio Capture" \
 -map 0:v -map 1:a \
 -preset ultrafast -c:v libx264 -tune zerolatency -b:v 900k \
 -f tee "[select=\'v:0\':f=mpegts]udp://127.0.0.1:5555|[select=\'v:0,a:0\':f=flv]rtmp://live-fra05.twitch.tv/app/stream_key"
```

See the full official docs for tee at http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#tee-1

Comment: Followed your advice and ran the following command `ffmpeg -threads:v 2 -threads:a 16 -filter_threads 2 -thread_queue_size 16 -y -f dshow -video_size 1920x1080 -pixel_format uyvy422 -framerate 25 -rtbufsize 500M -i video="Decklink Video Capture" -f dshow -rtbufsize 500M -i audio="Decklink Audio Capture" -map 0:v -map 1:a -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset ultrafast -c:v libx264 -crf 28 -g 10 -tune zerolatency -c:a libmp3lame -f tee "[select=\'0:v:0\':f=mpegts]udp://127.0.0.1:5555|[select=\'0:v:0,1:a:0\':f=flv]rtmp://live-fra05.twitch.tv/app/stream_key"`

Got the error: https://imgur.com/Nz6aYgA

Comment: Got rid of selectors and and only ran `..... -f tee "[f=mpegts]udp://127.0.0.1:5555|[f=flv]rtmp://live-fra05.twitch.tv/app/stream_key"` . UDP worked, Twitch shows Live but can't play the stream. What could be the problem? 
Also, the output is `frame=  368 fps= 25 q=34.0 size=N/A time=00:00:14.72 bitrate=N/A speed=   1x` . Those `N/A`s look strange, does not it?

Comment: Selectors should not have file index in front. See the docs.

Comment: Fixed that, still not working for Twitch. Although it works separately when it is encoding only for Twitch or when it is encoding twice, one for UDP and another for Twitch.

Comment: i'm just trying to tee to a file and a pipe, but I *still* get the "does not contain any stream" even when I add the select part...